# C# appending data to DIV in chat script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I created a chat application in ASP.NET C# using AJAX Timer and I am unable to control scroll bar and cannot select text due to regular update of `updatepanel`. Now, I want what are the alternate ways to append data received from database to DIV. Using C# with AJAX or jQuery or JavaScript how can I append retrieved text to DIV?

**Portion of my code**

```
while(dr.read())
{
   string chatvalues = dr[0].ToString();
   // How to append this chatvalues a DIV
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want plain text, and assuming your div has an id of divChat and is set to runat="server", you could do something like:

```
var sbChatData = new System.Text.StringBuilder(1000);
while(dr.read())
{
   sbChatData.AppendLine(dr[0].ToString());
}
divChat.InnerText += sbChatData.ToString();
```

**Update**

An alternative to posting back or using update panels is to use ajax requests or static page methods to retrieve the values that you want to use in the div.

Here is a quick example using Page Methods:

1) If you don't have it already, add a script manager to your page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />
```

2) Add a static method to your page to fetch the chat content:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetChatData()
    {
        // Some additional code; you will probably also need to pass a paramter for the chat id
        var sbChatData = new System.Text.StringBuilder(1000);
        while (dr.read())
        {
            sbChatData.AppendLine(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        return sbChatData.ToString();
    }
```

3) Add javascript to fetch the chat data and update the div:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateChatData() {
        var sChatData = PageMethods.GetChatData();
        if (sChatData != null) {
            document.getElementById('divChat').innerText = sChatData;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is keep on appending complete values along with old values.

Comment: @Madcoder. If you are reading all of the values out of the database each time, you can change `divChat.InnerText +=` to `divChat.InnerText =`

Comment: But if I write this in Timer_Tick then also I am encountering same issues. If I write the same in Page_Load I have to reload each time to update values.

Comment: Sorry, which issue are you encountering in timer_tick?

Comment: Unable to select text from DIV.

Comment: and unable to scrollup and scrolldown scroll bar.

Comment: @Madcoder.: I've updated the answer with an alternative approach (loading the div from the client side instead).